# rqt_graph pyqt binding of qt_gui_cpp library

Tags: pyqt5, ros

I am using ROS-melodic in ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I am getting this error:

```
Could not import "pyqt" bindings of qt_gui_cpp library - so C++ plugins will not be available:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui_cpp/cpp_binding_helper.py", line 43, in <module>
    from . import libqt_gui_cpp_sip
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_libqt_gui_cpp_sip)
```

however I have installed pyqt5 and pydot manually, rqt_graph shows up but with this warning. I want to know what can I do to get it right? Is this going to be problem in future? Now rqt_graph is loading but I don't know if this will mess up/create lacking in the graph?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling double packages if any using

```
     pip3 uninstall PyQt5-sip PyQt5
```

Then try importing it in python3 to check if any other version is there.
If the import is successful then try running the command again

```
     rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
```

if still some error exists install

```
     pip3 install PyQt5==5.12
```